# C++ Why does my recursion function return random characters or fail completely?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am working on creating a recursion function that tells me when there are no more numbers in a string that I pass into it. For some reason, the recursion works fine and stops when there are no more numbers.  However, when I try to return the numbers and use them in my code, I either get random characters or it will fail the program if I set the function to a variable string. Here is my code:

```
   if (checkX(equalsLocation, math)) {
        cout << "Start on the left side, x is on the right" << endl;
        xSide = 1;
        cout << partOneFinder(0, equalsLocation, math, "") << endl;
}
```

And then my function is here:

```
string partOneFinder(int current, int max, string math, string total) {
    cout << "This is the current iteration: " << current << "and the string: " << total <<endl;
    if (((math[current] == '0') || (math[current] == '1') || (math[current] == '2') || (math[current] == '3') || (math[current] == '4') || (math[current] == '5') ||
        (math[current] == '6') || (math[current] == '7') || (math[current] == '8') || (math[current] == '9')) && current <= max)
    {
        total += math[current];
        partOneFinder(current + 1, max, math, total);

    } else if (math[current] == 'x'){
        cout << "FOUND X!" << endl;
    }
    else  {
        string testTotal = total;
        return testTotal;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not [`isdigit((unsigned char)math[current])`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit) instead of `(math[current] == '0') || ... (math[current] == '9')`?

Comment: It's _undefined behavior_, you even get a compiler warning about your mistake. I am voting to close as _not reproducible_, because that's the very nature of UB.

Comment: You are taking your strings by value, not by reference, and every time you pass them to the next recursion you just copy the whole string into the new function's scope. Also, you are not returning anything in most code paths, so the caller is getting garbage.

Answer (score 4):

You have to execute `return` statement in all execution paths of non-void function, or *undefined behavior* is invoked.

```
string partOneFinder(int current, int max, string math, string total) {
    cout << "This is the current iteration: " << current << "and the string: " << total <<endl;
    if (((math[current] == '0') || (math[current] == '1') || (math[current] == '2') || (math[current] == '3') || (math[current] == '4') || (math[current] == '5') ||
        (math[current] == '6') || (math[current] == '7') || (math[current] == '8') || (math[current] == '9')) && current <= max)
    {
        total += math[current];
        // return something (I guessed to return the result of recursive call)
        return partOneFinder(current + 1, max, math, total);

    } else if (math[current] == 'x'){
        cout << "FOUND X!" << endl;
        // return something (I couldn't guess)
        return "";
    }
    else  {
        string testTotal = total;
        return testTotal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it! I didn't realize you needed a return statement for every option!